# Selenium how to consistently scrape product price in google shopping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When i scrape price in google shopping, i see there is 3 possible:

- there is only price `4.100.000 ₫.`
- there are price and used tag `4.100.000 ₫.` `Đã qua sử dụng`
- there are current  price and old price

number 1 and 2 are the same and can scrape using `.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.QIrs8 span").text` but with number 3, span class change into `a8Pemb OFFNJ` or still `QIrs8` but the text will change into something like `3.992.000 ₫ Giá cũ: 4.391.000 ₫.` I think it all depend on the shop that list the product.

My code so far:

```
def gg_shopping(query):
  search = query.replace(' ', '+')
  big_list = []
  url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search}&tbm=shop'
  driver.get(url)
  products = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.sh-dgr__gr-auto')))
  for product in products:
    item = Item(
      url=product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a").get_attribute('href'),
      name=product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3[class*='tAxDx']").text,
      # current_price=Decimal(0),
      current_price=(product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.QIrs8 span").text.replace("₫", "").replace(".","").replace(" ","")),
      place=product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='aULzUe IuHnof']").text,
      img=product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img").get_attribute('src'),
      date_add=datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
    )
    print(item)
    item, created = Product.objects.update_or_create(
      name=item.name,
      place=item.place,
      defaults={
        'current_price': item.current_price,
        'img': item.img,
        'url': item.url,
        'date_add': item.date_add
      }
    )
    big_list.append(item)
  return big_list
```

My dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class Item:
  url: str
  name: str
  current_price: Decimal
  place: str
  img: str
  date_add: datetime.datetime
```

Selenium import and relate:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price selector is always `span.a8Pemb.OFFNJ`, not sure why you rely in cases 1,2 on hidden element which is actually helper for some conditions that are known only by Google.

You can test it via this [link](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=573120737&tbm=shop&sxsrf=AM9HkKm0Kp77NafBJE-ebwHwUZV1pTSzuw:1697187257070&q=cat&tbs=mr:1,sales:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRjsyc0_KBAxX9HxAIHSWsCP8Q7KEGCNQHKAA&biw=1680&bih=868&dpr=2).

In data from that link there are 3 cases: prices, prices with tags, prices with discount. Just enter css locator `span.a8Pemb.OFFNJ` in Chrome Elements tab and you would see that it is unique price locator for every product card.